# Mongoose - FindOne and Search inside and Array

Tags: reactjs, json, mongodb, mongoose

In my users collection i'm storing inside an array a set of wishlist items as follow

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61840f03cfd5c0b680648f2c"),
    "email" : "xxxxxx@domain.com",
    "wishlist" : [ 
        ObjectId("6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc"), 
        ObjectId("61825f026d0fd99ef70380fd")
    ]
}
```

In my React Product page i want to check if the product has already been added to the whishlist, based on the email, and the objectID saved on the wishlist array ((i.e. 6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc) .

Despite the effort i can not understand how to write the query using mongoose.

The best solution I came up with is

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    email: "xxxxxx@domain.com",
    "user.wishlist" : "6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc",
    
    }).select('wishlist').exec()
```

But i'm getting an empty array as a result. If the product is found i want to return the objectId of the product.
How do I explicitly tell mongoose select the document matching a specific email address and then map into each element of the wishlist array in order to find the matching product?

For sake of clarity below is my user model

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
    },
    wishlist:[{type:ObjectId, ref:"Product"}],
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your query is wrong. You are trying to find into `user.wishlist` but in your schema the field is only `wishlist`.

So you need this query:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    email: "xxxxxx@domain.com",
    "wishlist" : "6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc"
}).select('wishlist').exec()
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YqE-UMO6kVm)

Also, I think mongoose parse automatically the string to `ObjectId` but maybe is needed to use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` like this:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    email: "xxxxxx@domain.com",
    "wishlist" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc")
}).select('wishlist').exec()
```

And least, if I've understood the question, you can avoid the `map` after the execution using projection stage like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N-_ENpG1LaO) to get only the element which match the value.

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
    email: "xxxxxx@domain.com",
    "wishlist" : "6182a45f38f323f21bec2ddc"
},
{
  "wishlist.$": 1
}).select('wishlist').exec()
```

Comment: Hello J.F. this is the correct solution! Your understanding is perfect! Thanks